# How to resolve the error some file crunching failed?

Tags: java, android, xml, java-6

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LvzDl.jpg)I am trying to import my project into android studio but the build is not successful. I am getting a run time exception:

> Error:java.lang.RuntimeException: Some file crunching failed, see logs for detail

I don't have any obvious errors in my project but it's not installing in mobile. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: Check your logcat.

Comment: Information:Gradle tasks [clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies]
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Some file crunching failed, see logs for details
Information:BUILD FAILED

Comment: Check your EventLog as well.

Answer (score 1):

This problem basically arise due to `drawable folder`. may be you are trying to converting extension of any image like `.jpeg to .png`.so please don't convert it. if this does not help then please share screenshot of your drawable folder item